# Setting Toolbar in SharePoint ListView Webparts using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, csom

I am trying to set a Toolbar for SharePoint list view web parts. I can able to done this in SSOM but cant in CSOM. I have tried by updating the Toolbar type element in the XMLDefinition property of the list view webpart. But it didn't works. 
      Also i tried by getting the MethodInfo as below.

```
Type[] toolbarMethodParamTypes = { Type.GetType("System.String") };
            MethodInfo setToolbarTypeMethod = webpartView.GetType().GetMethod("SetToolbarType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, toolbarMethodParamTypes, null);
```

But it returns null.

Is there any alternate ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to set toolbar using CSOM. So we have decided to set the toolbar using Jquery. I have added the below script in the JSLink of the webpart proerties.

```
    function hideToolbar(renderCtx) {
    var toolbar=renderCtx.viewTitle;
    if(toolbar != "")
    {
        if(toolbar=="None")
        renderCtx.ListSchema.Toolbar="None";
        else if(toolbar=="Freeform")
        renderCtx.ListSchema.Toolbar="Freeform";
    }
}
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {};
    overrideContext.OnPreRender = hideToolbar;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

I have set the ViewTitle in my CSOM code when the webpart added in the page.